# mysql_connect() : Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to connect to mysql and am getting an error.
I put my servers ip address in and used port 3306 whihch post should be used?

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("serer.ip:port", "user", "pass")
 or die(mysql_error());

 if ($connection) {$msg = "success";}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<? echo "$msg"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error its producing:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/admin/domains/domain.com.au/public_html/db_connect.php on line 3
>       Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: chances is that you did not allow your user `admin` to connect via the server `server1.myserver.com`. Make sure that `server1.myserver.com` is in the list of host that the user can connect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user, $db_pass) or die("Error connecting to database");
```

The port is automatically selected as 3306.

Also double check to make sure your username and password for connecting are correct and allowed access.

Comment: I was using my cpanel user and password not MYSQL, me = idiot!, thanks @Josh K